# Как сделать вложеный ключ в обьекте JS?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив:

```
[ 'this', 'is', 'my', 'first', 'app' ]
```

для примера.

Нужно вернуть такой объект

```
{ this:is:my:first:app: }.
```

То есть объект с вложенным свойством.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду, в массиве `my`, `project` и `name` что из себя представляют: строки или объекты? И в конечном итоге, что должно чем стать. Было бы неплохо, если бы вы еще привели "живой" пример данных до и после.

Comment: принимает строки, а должен быть обьект с 1 строкой

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @Grundy, ну мимо же?

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему эт? то же самое - из массива строк собрать объект. Правда остается вопрос тот ли объект все собирают, который нужен автору, но в этом случае все приведенные ответ неверны будут.

Comment: почему все ответы у меня выводяться без 4-5 элементов?

Comment: @Tryni, выводятся где? и что значит _без 4-5 элементов_?

Comment: @Grundy вот скрин - https://imgur.com/ZhLyWFX

Comment: попробуй сохранить результат в переменную и только затем вывести в console.log: `console.log(JSON.stringify(result))`

Comment: @Grundy Работает, но в чем проблема без stringify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
console.log(
  [ 'this', 'is', 'my', 'first', 'app' ] 
    .reduceRight((res, val) => ({[val]: res}))
)
```

Comment: вместо reverse+reduce можно reduceRight

Comment: проверка `res` лишняя - без неё будет то же самое. а если вторым аргументом передать пустой объект, то получится как у меня.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var myArr = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'first', 'app'];
var temp = "";
for (var i = myArr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  temp = temp ? temp : myArr[i];
  if (myArr[i - 1]) {
    temp = {[myArr[i - 1]]: temp};
  }
  
  
}
console.log("temp", temp);
```

Comment: Но вывод такой - temp { this: { is: { my: [Object] } } }, без 4-5 елемента

Comment: @Tryni С выводом всё ок, это особенность вашей консоли, у вас 4-5 элементы просто свёрнуты методом toString.

Comment: @Darth Danke)) Все правильно.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'first', 'app']
var res = {}

for (var x=res, i=0; i<a.length; ++i) {
  x = x[a[i]] = {}
}

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const arr = ["my", "project", "name"]

 const = {
     arr[0]: "Helllo",
     arr[1]: "Yes",
     arr[2]: "world"
 }
```

На выходе будет объект с ключами которые являются элементами массива.

Comment: Нужно что бы был 1 ключ